# Nested For-Loops - Remove Both Elements i and j

Tags: lua

I'm using a game-making framework implemented in Lua to keep busy in quarantine. I'm making a simple platformer with ECS/DOP, and I wanted to generate collision geometry derived from a tilemap rather than just checking for collisions with all tiles.

Each tile has a bounding box component that points to a list that contains the basic shapes. Each shape stores the edges of the bounding box as {{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}. The first step in this process is to parse a TileMap table that contains only tilenames, then insert a copy of the corresponding bounding-box translated by the row/column * grid_dimension into a table named BBOX. The next step is to delete all instances of an edge if it is a duplicate illustrated by this image

[image]

which is where I'm stuck.

The desired, basic edge-deletion algorithm looks like this:

```
for i = #BBOX, 1, -1 do
    local edge1 = BBOX[i]
    for j = i, 1, -1 do
        local edge2 = BBOX[j]
        same_edge = edge1 == edge2 -- Not the actual comparison, just the outcome of it
        if same_edge and i ~= j then
           BBOX[i] = nil
           BBOX[j] = nil
        end
    end
end
```

The issue is of course that this errors when **i** is equal to a **j** that was removed earlier in the loop. I've looked around and haven't been able to find a way to remove all instances of duplicate values in lua, only solutions that care about uniqueness. Has anyone found an efficient method of doing this or something similar?

Comment: You can set your keys to a value unique to each edge, essentially the key would what you are using for your comparison. this will remove duplicate values.

Comment: So make the key based on the value of the edge itself? That's a cool idea. How would I go about deleting the last instance of a duplicate though? I can see how BBOX[edge_key] = edge is beneficial for making a table of unique values, but getting rid of the last unique seems a bit hairy.

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean by `getting rid of the last unique`. if you use `edge_key` and lets say `edge1` and `edge2` are the same, then `BBOX[edge1_key] = edge1` followed by `BBOX[edge2_key] = edge2`  is only 1 table entry not 2

Comment: Basically, in the end I want BBOX[edge2_key] and BBOX[edge1_key] to return nil. Duplicate edges means they are in the interior of the larger rectangle (they would be the dotted lines in the image above) and both edges need to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the value unique to each key you can better detect duplicates.
we will call this unique value `edge.key`.

If an edge will only exist at most twice then:

```
BBOX[edge.key] = BBOX[edge.key] == nil and edge or nil
```

will do the trick.

But where an edge may exist any arbitrary number of time we can do something like this:

```
local duplicateEdges = {}

for i = #BBOX, 1, -1 do
  if BBOX[edge_key] then
    duplicateEdges[edge_key] = true
  else
    BBOX[edge_key] = edge
  end

  for j = i, 1, -1 do
    if BBOX[edge_key] then
      duplicateEdges[edge_key] = true
    else
      BBOX[edge_key] = edge
    end
  end
end

for k in pairs(duplicateEdges) do
  BBOX[k] = nil
end
```

Comment: I ended up doing the second, but replaced all `edge_key`'s with i/j where applicable and just used if `BBOX[i] == BBOX[j] then duplicateEdges[i] = true, duplicateEdges[j] = true`. I was worried about performance but it seems just fine. Thanks @Nifim